# Why isn't my isolated scope working in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've been trying for ages and cannot work out what is wrong here. Take a look at this [code on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SG21ci604czUF8d2sV1n).
Gold star to the first person who can tell me why, in my directive, the isolated scope properties are coming through as "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I get the gold star myself! The controller needs to be on an ancestor element to the directive in order that the scope properties come through.